# Find unbiased for $\theta$ of $\hat{\theta_1} = (n+1) ~y_{(1)}$given a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, \theta]$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Show that $\hat{\theta_1} = (n+1) ~y_{(1)}$ is unbiased for $\theta$.

For $$P[Y_i \le Y] = 1 - y/\theta$$ 
Then for $ P[Y_{(1)} < y] = 1 - [1-F_{(Y_i)} (y)]^n$ which should equal to $1 - [1-(1-y/\theta)]^n = 1 - [y/\theta]^n$ However, $F_{Y_{(1)}}(y)$ is supposed to be $1 - (1-y/\theta)^n$....where is my derivation goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your whole class has posted this at some point in the last week or so.  If $P[Y\le y]=1-y/\theta$ then $P[Y \le 0]=1$ and $P[Y \le \theta]=0$ which does not look right!

Comment: I know is wrong. What is wrong in what I wrote above, then?

Comment: I think it boil down to whether $P[Y_i \le y] = y/\theta or 1-y/\theta$. My calculation is $$P[Y_i \le y] = \int_y^{\theta} 1/\theta dx= 1-y/\theta$$, is this right?

Comment: $P[Y\le y]=y / \theta$.  $P[Y\le y]=F_Y(y)=\int _0^y f(x)dx$

Comment: Could you show your process as I show mine above as you can point out the mistake

Comment: Do I just use 1 - what I have above since the integral is from y to $\theta$. In other words, if the integral is from $\theta$ to $y$, $1 - y/\theta$ will be the right answer right?

Comment: $y_{(1)}$ is the minimum value I take it. You don't mention. You want $1-(P[Y>y])^n = 1-(1-P[Y \le y])^n$. Where $P[Y>y] = \int_y^\theta dx/\theta$